# Ajax load doubles content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a site built using wordpress as the cms and the index has a long accordian style list of post titles and once you click on this heading the content for that post is loaded via ajax into the index page.

I have the problem that when the heading  is clicked again, it loads the post content again and if you click a different heading it won't close and remove the previous one that has been clicked.

I am new to working with ajax and unsure how to go about fixing this. Is there a way to make the content be removed once the heading is clicked a second time to close the accordion or another heading is clicked to expand and open. Live site is here: http://www.minervasydney.com/

Below is the code for my ajax and the part in my index file that lists the headings. If anyone has ideas it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

AJAX

```
        $("a.exhibitionInformation").on("click", function(event) {

        var exhibitionContainer = $(this).parent(".exhibition");
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var doc = $(this).next(".exhibitionDocuments");
        var title = convertToSlug($(this).text().split("\n")[1]);
        var slug = $(this).attr("data-slug");
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

        if($(doc).is(':not(:hidden)')) {
            $(doc).slideToggle();
        } else {            


            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    var content = $(data).find(".single-document");                 
                    $(doc).append(content).slideToggle(300);                    
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: exhibitionContainer.offset().top - 26 });
                    window.location.hash = slug;
                }           
            });

        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });


    //ajaxstarStop Loading
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
        $( "#loading" ).fadeIn(100);
    });

    $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
        $( "#loading" ).fadeOut();
    });     


    function convertToSlug(Text)
    {
        return Text
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace(/ /g,'-')
            .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
            ;
    }
```

INDEX

```
            <section class="exhibition">

            <a class="exhibitionInformation" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-slug="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
                <span class="dates"><?php echo types_render_field("dates", array("argument1"=>"value1")); ?></span>
                <span class="opening"><?php echo types_render_field("opening", array("argument1"=>"value1")); ?></span>
                <span class="title">&#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</span>
                <span class="artist"><?php echo types_render_field("artist", array("argument1"=>"value1")); ?></span>
                <span class="extra"><?php echo types_render_field("extra", array("argument1"=>"value1")); ?></span>
            </a>


            <article class="exhibitionDocuments">

            </article>

        </section>
```

Comment: before posting answer copy and test this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/6/ if i'm not wrong

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer thanks for your suggestion in the fiddle. Unfortunately it was still doubling the content once the heading was clicked again. It also seemed to affect the slide toggle, as it wouldn't remain open when it was clicked. Is there another way you can think of make the part that was loaded by ajax be removed once the heading is clicked a second time? thanks!

Comment: Did you mean you want to abort ajax request if another or current heading clicked? test this https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find(".single-document");                 
        $(doc).append(content).slideToggle(300);                    
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: exhibitionContainer.offset().top - 26 });
        window.location.hash = slug;
    }           
});
```

On the second line under *success*, change `.append` to `.html`.

The line should now be:

```
$(doc).html(content).slideToggle(300);
```

It will load the content AND remove previous if there was.

---

**EDIT**

To close a previously opened `.exhibitionDocuments`:

```
$(document).find(".exhibitionDocuments").hide();
```

Place it on top of your success callback.
   *(right before `var content = $(data).find(".single-document");`)*

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Within this, is there a way to also close an open toggle when a new heading is clicked?